# Taiwan proof of funds for Filipino visa exempt tourist

Tags: filipino-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, taiwan

I will travel to Taiwan with my girlfriend who is a Filipno national. Looking at [the Visa-exempt entry page at the BOCA website](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-149-4486-7785a-2.html), it says

> Holders of Brunei, Philippines, Russia and Thailand passports must have: A proof of accommodation (hotel) booking, host / sponsor's contact information and sufficient travel funds.

I can not find a definition of "sufficient funds" anywhere. She doesn't have a lot of money in the bank since she puts most of the salary form her job as a teacher into her family business.

Would it be enough if I, as a Swedish passport holder, have "proof of funds" from my bank, even though we are only in a relationship but not married?